# use ape to phase a fasta file and create a DNAbin file as output, then test tajima's D using pegas

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to complete the very simple task of reading in an unphased fasta file and phasing it using ape, and then calculating Tajima's D using pegas, but #my data doesn't seem to be reading in correctly. Input and output is as #follows:

```
library("ape")
library("adegenet")
library("ade4")
library("pegas")

DNAbin8c18 <- read.dna(file="fasta8c18.fa", format="f")
```

I shouldn't need to attach any data since I've just generated the file, but since the data() command was in the manual, I executeed

```
data(DNAbin8c18)
```

and got

> Warning message: In data(DNAbin8c18) : data set ‘DNAbin8c18’ not found

I know that data() only works in certain contexts, so maybe this isn't a big deal. I looked at what had been loaded

```
DNAbin8c18

817452 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

All sequences of same length: 96 

Labels: 
CLocus_12706_Sample_1_Locus_34105_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s08... 
CLocus_12706_Sample_2_Locus_31118_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s08... 
CLocus_12706_Sample_3_Locus_30313_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s09... 
CLocus_12706_Sample_5_Locus_33345_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s09... 
CLocus_12706_Sample_7_Locus_37388_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s09... 
CLocus_12706_Sample_8_Locus_29451_Allele_0 [BayOfIslands_s09... ...

More than 10 million nucleotides: not printing base composition
```

so it looks like the data should be fine. Because of this, I tried what I want to do

```
tajima.test(DNAbin8c18)
```

and got

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2489.3 Gb

Many people have completed this same test using as many or more SNPs that I have, and also using FASTA files, but is it possible that mine is too big, or can you see another issue?

The data file can be downloaded at the following link
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6qb8IlaQGFZLVRYeXMwRnpMTUU

I have also sent and earlier version of this question, with the data, to the r-sig-genetics mailing list, but I have not heard back.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Ella

Comment: Have you tried running the `tajima.test` on a subset of your data? It is likely your data set is too big. The issue is not the number of snps but the number of samples. Also, `data` is only used to load objects that come with packages e.g. `data(iris)`.

Comment: Furthermore, it looks like `tajima.test` has a limit of 50K-99,999 sequences (100K sequence throws an error). So are going to need to reduce the size of your data.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just got a note from the developer giving me a suggestion to run

Comment: Next time, consider asking at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comment. Indeed, you are correct. The developer just emailed me with the following very helpful comments.
The problem is that your data are too big (too many sequences) and tajima.test() needs to compute the matrix of all pairwise distances. You could this check by trying:

```
dist.dna(DNAbin8c18, "N")
```

One possibility for you is to sample randomly some observations, and repeat this many times, eg:

```
tajima.test(DNAbin8c18[sample(n, size = 1000), ])
```

This could be:

```
N <- 1000 # number of repeats
RES <- matrix(N, 3)
for (i in 1:N)
    RES[, i] <- unlist(tajima.test(DNAbin8c18[sample(n, size = 10000), ]))
```

You may adjust N and 'size =' to have something not too long to run. Then you may look at the distribution of the columns of RES.